# Play 360 video in react js?

Tags: reactjs, video

How do I play 360 video in react js?
None of the video player libraries seem to support it except a few really old ones that have been outdated for many years.

Comment: It's not obvious what you've tried. Is there anything useful [from basic research](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=javascript+360+video+player)?